# Terminology Trouble with respect to lattice structures

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

I am having an issue understanding terminology in a chemistry text book I am reading.

I am reading about lattice structures and it keep interchanging with the word 'basis'.

So for context, it refers to a CsCl structure as a BCC lattice with alternating Cs Cl ions, which I understand, but the says it can be refer to as a SC with basis and that my confusion what are they referring to as the basis, the additional atom in the centre, why not just say that it just a BCC, why describe it in terms of basis, is there a importance to this way of describing it, that I am missing?

Comment: The book is being sloppy (at best). A 'bcc lattice' with alternating Cs and Cl ions, well, isn't a bcc lattice - it does not have the symmetry required of a real bcc lattice, since Cs isn't Cl (and vice versa). So, the 'basis' is the Cs-Cl pair, and the Bravais lattice is indeed simple cubic. (The Bravais lattice type describes the translational symmetry, the basis is whatever is hung on each lattice point.) See, for example, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35273/why-are-there-only-7-types-of-unit-cells-and-14-types-of-bravais-lattices/35277#35277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the cubic unit cell with Cs in the centre and Cl on each vertex of the cube. That's your body-centred cubic cell if I understood correctly. I'll denote it I to be clear. Then consider the cube whose opposite vertices are the centre and one corner. I'll denote it II. Then it should be obvious enough that I is made of 8 replica of II, which all share the centre Cs. Both I and II are perfectly adequate representation of the crystal. But II is smaller. The smallest actually, and it is often called a primitive cell for that reason.

Comment: That's completely wrong. CsCl has a primitive cubic structure because its associated lattice is primitive cubic, not centered. Primitive and centering have nothing to do with dimension, but depend on the arrangment of lattice points (not atoms) in the geometrical space.